# Any way or software to decompile swf to extract mxml file?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash, mxml, swf-decompiler

Does anybody know any way or any software which could decompile swf file to generate the source code mxml file and actionscript file? If any, could you give me a little more detail about how to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flex Compiler translates MXML into ActionScript before compiling it.  There is going to be no way to start with the SWF and get the MMXL Code.

There are plenty of decompiler options if you need the ActionScript code.  [Sothink has one](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/).  I have used another SoThink products and it has been solid.

There could be moral and legal issues surrounding the use of decompilers, so using one is not a decision I'd take lightly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my concern is currently I want to see some detail information for a flex project (such as how to generate some special id), so I want to learn the specific api it use. So after mxml translating to actionscript, is it possible to see these detail information?

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to parse and figure out the ActionScript.  If you want to learn how to use an API, I strongly suggest you look up the documentation on that API; or as the original developers for documentaiton.  Public APIs often have documentation, and private APIS--given you are accessing them legitimately--often have documentation available too.

Answer (score 1):

Flash Decompiler Trillix is able to decompile SWF file and return source code. [Flash Decompiler](http://www.flash-decompiler.com/)